# Disabling li element in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, html-lists

I am trying to programmatically disable an ul depending on what the outcome of the IF statement is, I have this HTML:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="tab1_placeholder" runat="server">
    <li class="active" runat="server" id="tab1">
        <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">
        1* </a>
    </li>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And then in the code I have:

```
if (System.Convert.ToInt32(Session["level"]) > 5)
{
   tab1.Disabled = true;
}
```

However this doesn't work as it doesn't disable it when the level is 9, I've also tried wrapping a PlaceHolder around it thinking that the PlaceHolder has a Disabled property however I thought wrong.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not a good approach for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute in HTML is not valid for all elements.  If I'm not mistaken, only `button, input, select, textarea, optgroup, option` and `fieldset` elements can actually have the disabled attribute.

So, no, this is not a valid approach.  I'm guessing you want to disable the links if level is 9?  You should instead target the `a` tags and add this to them:

```
onclick="return false;"
```

In C# code:

```
aElement.attributes.add("onclick", "return false");
```

Where aElement is the anchor element with `runat="server"` and `ID="aElement"`

Comment: I don't want to be setting an onclick. I have this code in my Page Load therefore I want these li elements disabled when the page loads

Comment: li elements don't have the disabled attribute.  You could disabling the actual a element, but I'm sure that will not work either.  That's why I proposed the above solution.

Comment: Why can't you use an onclick attribute?

Comment: Because it would require the user to click?

Comment: Then what are you trying to accomplish by disabling the li?  Preventing the user from being able to click it, right?  That's exactly what setting onclick="return false"; on the anchor tags does - it prevents the user from clicking and following the link.  It's effectively the same as disabling the li containing the a element.  Unless I'm completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work ? :/ Also, if a add an attribute programtically for example class="locked" could it be changed on the client side? Because I want it to always remain disabled or locked so the user cannot tamper with the code to bypass the system

Comment: Everything client side can be tampered with on the client.  You should never *trust* on the client.

Comment: So what would be the best option to keep it remain disabled so the client cannot tamper with it?

Comment: Well, instead of disabling the tab to prevent the user from seeing/opening it, just don't output any content to the tab.  That way, if the user tampers with the code, like removes the onclick attribute, there is nothing there for him to see.  Any content/data you pass on to the client can be seen by the client.  All authorization/authentication rules should be enforced on the server side and the client should only receive data he's authorized/allowed to see.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info, is their any way of using tabs that can be disabled?